# several asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

which is the best way, or the right way to launch several AsyncTask at once?

currently executed as follows form:

```
new VoyAir().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/voya ir.php");
new Voy().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/voy.php");
new Vome().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/vome.php");
new gus().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/gus.php");
```

but I'm programming in android 4.0.3 and it not function correctly.
Could you give an example of the best way to do this? thanks

Comment: What is the problem with the code you posted? All of your tasks will be executed (sequentially if that is 4.0.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use such code to do that regardless of OS version:

```
public class WebnetMobileTools {
    public static <P, T extends AsyncTask<P, ?, ?>> void executeAsyncTask(T task, P... params) {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
           task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
       } else {
           task.execute(params);
       }
    }
}
```

To use it, instead of

```
new VoyAir().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/voya ir.php");
```

you do

```
WebnetMobileTools.executeAsyncTask( new VoyAir(), 
                     "http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/voya ir.php");
```

This will always run all launched async tasks in paralell as it used to work up to Android 3.0 where change was introduced.